# Shouldn't dead links be removed?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, broken-link

The following Meta question mentions dead links should be removed; [Which flag should I use to report a dead link?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186930/which-flag-should-i-use-to-report-a-dead-link)

Yet [my suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6413996) doing just that was rejected.

So shouldn't dead links be removed?

Comment: I'd say it's by now so bad that the whole answer can simply go. It's link only and - as you say - the majority is dead. I wouldn't have rejected the edit, but I'm not sure it's worth salvaging anyway.

Comment: Dead links should be *replaced*.  If you don't have time to find the substitutes then just leave it for somebody that does.

Answer (score 5):

**Just** removing a dead link does not really improve a post.
It arguably makes it worse, as the notice that there was something more is gone.

The proper thing to do when you notice dead links, depending on circumstances, is one of:

- Notify the author with a comment.
- Replace it with a link to an [archived version](http://www.archive.org), or another link to an equivalent source.
- Finally flag it as link-only answerr to get it removed (also add a comment).

Comment: interesting.. looks like its completely deleted now, so instead of people having access to the one link that was working, its better to not have any links?

Comment: @Akash It was a link-only answer, severely dated (and decomposing), and there are lots of proper answers on the question. So, not really a loss. (BTW: It was animuson did the deed.)