# What should happen to questions using codeviewer.org for sharing code?

Tags: discussion, flags, broken-link

About a month ago I encountered [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42319286) in the review queue, for <10K users, it said:

> MALWARE ALERT, DO NOT CLICK ON OP's LINK!!!

I voted to delete the answer, but I also checked out the question, which is now deleted, to see what the answerer was talking about. It seems that the link he was referring to is http://codeviewer.org/view/code:45be.

I clicked that link, and it seems that the domain is "for sale", but it also shows a giant ad sometimes. At that time I didn't realize that it could have been a code sharing website, so I flagged the post as spam (since it just links to ads), only to be declined later on (even though the post was deleted a day after my flag).

However, doing a [quick search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=codeviewer.org) it seems that there are ~70 other posts referring to codeviewer.org. Considering that they add no value, show ads, and may be harmful (according to the answerer), I was wondering what actions should be taken.

I've checked Meta ([this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105128/how-to-handle-link-rot-and-broken-links), [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262038/how-to-flag-dead-links) and [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278677/shouldnt-dead-links-be-removed)), and it seems that the concensus is to fix where possible, to leave a comment to the author and otherwise to flag the posts.

Considering that most posts are pretty old, and I haven't been able to retrieve any of those codeviewer.org links on archive.org so far, I guess flagging is the right way to go, but:

- What flag should I use (considering that my spam flag was declined)?
- Is it a problem if I flag multiple of these posts in a short amount of time?

Comment: Ah the pitfalls of using external sites to display code. *cough* jsfiddle *cough*.

Comment: small question. if the code is long (and putting it within the question/answer wouldn't be a good idea), which website do you suggest we host the code on?

Comment: @user1993, The short answer is: you don't put it only on an external site. Debugging questions *require* the code to be in the question. If it is too long for a question, then it is probably not a *minimal* MCVE. You should edit it down to be so. If you *must* link an external site, try to make an archive. [This answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/73635/22966) has a bookmarklet which will cause archive.org to create an archive of the URL you are currently viewing.

Comment: @user1993: That bookmarklet to cause archive.org to create an archive is: `javascript:void(window.open('https://web.archive.org/save/'+location.href))`

Comment: I had a [similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336182/previously-safe-link-now-potentially-malicious) a while back, and it seemed like the consensus was "fix if possible, remove link if not". Not sure if that helps or not.

Comment: @evolutionxbox don't forget to *cough* around Plunker too

Comment: @Makyen so how's archive.org not an external site? :) It could go down the same as any other page, right?

Comment: @Botis, Yes, it's an external site. Perhaps I did not communicate: I stated that the question *must* have the code in the question itself. For debugging questions, that is a clear, explicit [*requirement* for the question to be on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Not having the code in the question is a common reason for such questions to be closed. However, having something on two separate systems does make it less likely that both disappear. Redundancy is one of the typical methods of increasing the probability that data will not be lost, but does not make the loss impossible.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Where the question doesn't need the link (aka the code has been copied over), I would edit out the link (when you are above 2K rep).

Those questions that lack code, vote to close as unclear/lacks MCVE and sprinkle downvotes to get these [roomba-ed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba).

The few that can't be roomba-ed, but don't have value either, vote to delete.

Only involve moderators if the Q/A pair is locked, making it impossible to execute any of the previously-mentioned methods.

For a clean-up project like this that has been posted on meta, feel free to post `cv-pls` or `delv-pls` requests, or ask for advice, in the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chat room. Visit the room's [FAQ](http://socvr.org/faq) before posting to understand the room rules. I've already left a message to make our regulars aware of this answer.

Comment: *their FAQ*? Perhaps you should be saying *our FAQ* instead?

Comment: @DavidG hmm, okay. The difference being that saying their FAQ doesn't disclose my affiliation with that room?

Comment: Partially, more like the language could be read as you are actively not affiliated. A minor issue, the edit is perfect.

Comment: "close to vote"?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Yeah, that's the new system, first you close a question, then you vote if it was done correctly (jk)