# Removing old links pointing to malicious or suspicious websites

Tags: discussion, support, external-links, broken-link

I was looking at old (2+ years) questions with the [owl-carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/owl-carousel), [owl-carousel-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/owl-carousel-2). In some of them users added links to the documentation. For some reasons those links aren't related now to the project, and when clicking them, they redirect to spam or adware websites.

Question is, should I edit or flag them every time when I see something like that, or is there any other way to fix it?

Comment: If you think the answers are valuable, and the link adds value to the answer, you can replace the link with a [wayback machine](https://archive.org/web/) variant from around the time the answer was posted. Afaik they rarely go down, and probably represent the content the author of that answer wanted to share.

Comment: Don't flag them, moderators won't deal with such links. Edit them if you can salvage the post.

Comment: What I was thinking @Martijn, since to replace the links with their corresponding from the wayback machine would be a hard work, I guess better would be to remove them from the questions, the ones corresponding to the first version are the bad ones. V2 has an updated Github documentation.

Comment: @Sebastian Palma Not hard at all. A link to http://oldsite.com posted on 2015-07-23 becomes https://web.archive.org/web/20150723/http://oldsite.com.

Comment: @AuxTaco, but you have to verify by opening it in a new tab that archive.org actually has a copy saved. SO posts, for instance, have to be manually archived as there are way too many for the WayBack to crawl all of them.

Comment: Related: [What should happen to questions using codeviewer.org for sharing code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345443/what-should-happen-to-questions-using-codeviewer-org-for-sharing-code). I asked this question myself a while ago, and even though it's about a completely different website, I guess the same answer applies here as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Moderators don't have time to deal with dead-link posts, [so don't flag for mod attention](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360224/removing-old-links-pointing-to-malicious-or-suspicious-websites?cb=1#comment537350_360224).  You can do everything that's useful by editing, unless it was a link-only answer and there's no copy anywhere else.  In which case flag it as not-an-answer, I think.

---

Look for an archived copy on the Wayback machine (https://archive.org/web/), or an updated link.  Wayback-machine links load slower (so are less nice for future readers), but are more future-proof.

If there's no new or archived copy you can find, it depends how essential the link was to the post.  If it was just further reading about something, you should maybe just remove it as long as the post still stands on its own.

If it was fairly important, you should edit the dead link into code-formatting or something (so it's not clickable), and leave a note explaining that it's dead or spammy now.  Maybe some future editor knows an equivalent resource to the one that is now gone.

---

Throwing out information by deleting links just because you're too busy to generate valid archive.org links is a bad idea.  **Only delete them if you did check and there's no archive.**

Unless they're not pointing to actively dangerous websites (not the usual ads from expired domains), just leave it alone if you're not going to take the time to do it right.  (leave a comment that the link is dead, maybe someone else will fix.)

If they are actively dangerous links, then take the extra time to properly Wayback it.  Or if you really must move on but don't want to leave it, edit it to put the URL in `code formatting` so it's not clickable, with a note that it's now malicious.

Comment: Not the downvoter, and I appreciate taking your time to answer. As per my comment, yes, being focused in many other things make for me this a difficult task. The reason of the question was _is there any other way to fix it?_, asking for possible ways, now I know it.

Comment: If the link was fairly important, then why would you edit the post? If it's important, then in case of an answer, it should probably be removed as NAA if it doesn't contain enough information in the answer itself (link-only answer). If it's a question and the link contains information necessary to solve the issue, then it should likely be closed as "off-topic" or "unclear what you're asking" if it's lacking context due to the missing link. Editing the deadlink to code is not a good edit if you ask me. Make sure that you're not polishing turds.

Comment: @g00glen00b: I was thinking of a case where the answer without the link could be salvaged into something still worth having, but less useful than before.  Or maybe you'd have to write a new paragraph to replace what it was linking to.  In many of the cases you describe, deletion sounds best.  Editing a link to code is only my suggestion as a stopgap when you know the link is actively harmful (e.g. hijacks your browser, not just shows irrelevant ads), but either you don't have time to look for an update or you want to preserve some history of what some answer linked to (rare).

Comment: I think deleting the link in those cases is the best. The revision history already "preserves some history", and I think that having an old link in a code block is going to be confusing for future readers. I would personally see if the q/a is salvageable without link, and if yes, edit it out, and if not, close/flag it.

Comment: @g00glen00b Yes, normally you should either find a replacement, leave it alone, or delete it if you've checked and not found a replacement.  Most links aren't so interesting that it's worth preserving the URL even when it's gone and there's no equivalent.  I mainly mentioned the put-in-code-block because of discussion under the question of "oh but it's so much work to check wayback-machine links".  Partly to make the point that even something that ugly is better than deleting *without looking for a replacement*, so just leaving things alone is usually better than doing a bad job.