# Should links to deleted SO questions be deleted from answers?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, broken-link

This edit https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27041040 deletes a link to a SO question from an answer because the linked question has been deleted in the meanwhile.

Is it more useful to delete the link as proposed in the edit to keep the answer "clean"?
Or should the answer better not be touched (maybe the question gets undeleted in the future again)?

Would the system not be able to handle such dead internal links better?

Comment: The link isn't really _dead_, it just requires 10k rep to see

Comment: This entire answer should be reduced to _“Libraries for reading MP3 metadata may work as well, as the metadata for videos seems to be stored in a similar, if not identical, format. That being said, you can give `TagLib#` a shot.”_. Most of this answer refers to some off-site resource or another. There is no long-term value in that.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278677/shouldnt-dead-links-be-removed and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300916/i-estimate-10-of-the-links-posted-here-are-dead-how-do-we-deal-with-them?noredirect=1&lq=1 as well as https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4794/what-to-do-when-you-find-a-bad-link-in-an-answer and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99228/how-should-we-deal-with-questions-that-have-broken-links

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The link is effectively dead. That 10k users can see these posts is not relevant. 10k have this privilege for curation purposes, not because we have a two tier repository with some links visible for high-rep users and not for the rest.

In the same way that if a link was protected with a password or something like that. If the linked content is not viewable by a random user, it should be considered dead. If the link can't be replaced by a better one or a cached copy, it should be removed.

The user who suggested the edit had less than 10k, so from their perspective the link was dead. They may not be even aware that the "see-deleted-content" privilege exists. In my opinion, the edit was legit and correctly approved.

Links should be used for support purposes only anyway. If an answer depends on a link to be a of any use, it should be flagged for deletion instead of edited.

Comment: You haven't checked if there is a cached copy available. There is [C# to read properties of video files?](https://web.archive.org/web/20170225230114/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396265/c-sharp-to-read-properties-of-video-files). According to the argumentation, which I fully support, the link should have been replaced with a cached copy. Have done it.